# asp.net it's running my c# methods automatically

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

when i start my asp page, automatically my methods in code behind are executed and i don't want that.

```cs
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {        
          //this method executes automatically
    }
```

I want the method `ConvertDataTabletoString()` run when I press a html button

ex.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->

Button OnClick="function()">Boton</Button
```

language: lang-js

```
<script>

    function function1()
    {
         cars = JSON.parse(ConvertDataTabletoString());
    }

</script>
```

Comment: can you share your script code ?

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't just call a serverside function like that,

Comment: Perhaps start at: http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: in C# right click `ConvertDataTabletoString` and select "Find all references" to see why it runs at page load.

Comment: @Krunal Patil do you refer to the javascript code?

Comment: @user3055336 You want the result of `ConvertDataTabletoString()` method into `JavaScript` variable? Why don't you implement same code inside `JavaScript` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following HTML on page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID='ScriptManager1' runat='server' EnablePageMethods='true' />
<asp:Button ID=”btnSave” runat=”server” Text=”Save” OnClientClick=”return CodeBehindMethodCall();” />
```

Now time to adjust our code behind so we can call it from JavaScript, we need to use `System.Web.Services` so add it in our code behind file

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

Whatever method we need to call from JavaScript, add **WebMethodattribute** to that method and that will easily be called by javaScript

```
[WebMethod]
public String ConvertDataTabletoString()
{
    // your code 
}
```

Now we will **call ConvertDataTabletoString from JavaScript**, so add the following JavaScript to the page:

```
function CodeBehindMethodCall()
{
    pageName.ConvertDataTabletoString();
}
```

As you can see we have not used web service but we changed a method to web method so it can be called from JavaScript but without converting a method into web method we can not call any code behind method from JavaScript.

This is how its done.

Comment: what is the pageName?

Comment: PageName is static page methods to an ASP.NET page and qualify them as Web methods. You can then call these methods from script as if they were part of a Web service, but without creating a separate .asmx file. To create Web methods in a page, import the System.Web.Services namespace and add a WebMethodAttribute attribute to each static method that you want to expose.

Comment: To be able to call static page methods as Web methods, you must set the EnablePageMethods attribute of the ScriptManager control to true. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @user3055336, if you find the answer useful please accept it as an answer, so that in future it helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

you can used below menioned code

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Log in" onclick="btnLogin_Click"/>
```

and your code behind

```
     protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConvertDataTabletoString();
        }
```

Comment: Looking at the question OP want the result of `ConvertDataTabletoString()` method call into `JavaScript` variable inside a `JavaScript` function.

Comment: That makes no sense.so we have to correct him

Comment: Yes. Alter your answer to guide him.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/calling-server-side-function-from-javascript-in-Asp-Net/

But I would create an webservice and consume it via javascript on the page.

Like here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb924552%28v=vs.110%29.aspx